# Goland ide highlight the 'limit'

Tags: goland

Goland ide highlight the 'limit' word in my SQLite queries as error, but query is correct:

How to fix it?

```sql
               select FILENAME,
                      CLIENT_NAME,
                      DT,
                      STATUS,
                      JOBID
                 from FAX
                order by DT desc
                limit 20
               offset ?
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was because I didn't choose the default dialect. By default it was MSSql